# Sort array of objects by by coincidence with another array JS REACT REDUX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have 2 arrays. 
FIRST looks like:

```
const arrOjObjects = [
{text: "HUF", value: 300.3803314317},
{text: "GBP", value: 0.7925201485},
{text: "IDR", value: 14127.9996377796},
{text: "ILS", value: 3.5020374898},
{text: "DKK", value: 6.7633795164}]
```

Second looks like:

```
const arr = ["ILS, "DKK"]
```

I need to sort arrOjObjects by some rule, if the elements of the object text match the element of the array arr, then the object must be first and all other objects behind it

I need  some sort rule, which will sort my arr to this state:

```
const arrOjObjects = [
{text: "ILS", value: 3.5020374898}, // ILS is in arr
{text: "DKK", value: 6.7633795164} //  DKK is in arr
{text: "HUF", value: 300.3803314317},
{text: "GBP", value: 0.7925201485},
{text: "IDR", value: 14127.9996377796},
]
```

Thanks for answers!

Comment: Could you please show us what you tried ?

Comment: do the items of the second array have to be in order of the second array?

Comment: Sorting like this ('A" things first and then not "A") is easier with two filters: `X.filter(arr.includes(x.text)).concat(X.filter(!arr.includes(x.text)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.sort`

```js
const arrOjObjects = [
 {text: "HUF", value: 300.3803314317},
 {text: "GBP", value: 0.7925201485},
 {text: "IDR", value: 14127.9996377796},
 {text: "ILS", value: 3.5020374898},
 {text: "DKK", value: 6.7633795164}]

 const arr = ["ILS", "DKK"];

 arrOjObjects.sort((a, b) => arr.includes(b.text) - arr.includes(a.text));

 console.log(arrOjObjects);
```

Comment: That's nice, but I guess the callback can be simplified to `arr.includes(b.text) - arr.includes(a.text)`

Comment: @georg we surely can do that, however, that does not work Node environment `jdoodle.com/a/1Ce3`, I am not sure why.

Comment: because you have `a.text` - `b.text` there, should be the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

i cant think of an elegant solution for your problem. But here's a straight forward way for solving your issue.

Firstly, find the elements you want according to your search array

```
let sorted = [];
for (let sortText of arr) {
   let res = arrOjObjects.find((obj) => {
       return obj.text === sortText;
   });
   if (res) sorted.push(res);
}
```

After which, slot in the remaining values that are not part of the search criteria

```
let remaining = arrOjObjects.filter((obj) => {
    return !arr.includes(obj.text);
});
sorted = [...sorted, ...remaining];
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```js
arrOjObjects.sort((a, b) => {
  if (arr.includes(a.text) && !arr.includes(b.text)) {
    return -1;
  } else if (!arr.includes(a.text) && arr.includes(b.text)) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return a.value - b.value;
  }
});
```